# Problems with CSV in Powershell

Tags: arrays, csv, powershell

I have imported a .csv file and i have the first column listed in a combobox in my form. I am trying to match the the selected data from the combobox with the corresponding row. For Example

Office,Server
Chicago,chicago1
New York, newyork1
Los Angeles, la1

When they select the $office, id like to create the next object the $server and reference it somewhere else.

```
$Offices = @(Import-CSV "C:\source\PrinterTable.csv")
$Array = $Offices.office | Sort-Object

ForEach ($Choice in $Array) {

    [void] $objListBox.Items.Add($Choice)

}

  $handler_Office_Click= 
{ 

   $officeSelected = $objListBox.SelectedItem
   $row = $officeSelected | where { $_.office -eq $officeSelected }
   $server = $row.server
explorer.exe \\$server


}
```

I've been googling for hours... please help!

Comment: To get this to show in the combobox AND as a selected item $office = $objlistbox.selecteditem had to go to the $handle_office_click function. Now im trying the same thing but telling it to call the $server... still need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out the fix, i had to bring my csv back to my $handler click, final code is

```
    $handler_Office_Click= 
{ 

        $officeSelected = $objListBox.SelectedItem
    $OffServer= ($PrinterTables | where {$_.office -eq $officeSelected}).server


explorer.exe \\$OffServer


}

$PrinterTables = @(Import-CSV "C:\Program Files (x86)\Helpdesk 2.0\PrinterTables.csv")
$ListedOffices = $PrinterTables.office | Sort-Object



ForEach ($Choice in $ListedOffices) {

    [void] $objListBox.Items.Add($Choice)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a selected office name, find a row in `$offices` that has a matching `office` field. Then select `server` field from this row.

```bsh
$row = $offices | where { $_.office -eq $office }
$server = $row.server
```

Comment: Maybe im doing this wrong... my list wasnt appearing if i left it outside the $handler_office_click so i did this:

      $handler_Office_Click= 
   { 
       
       $officeSelected = $objListBox.SelectedItem
       $row = $officeSelected | where { $_.office -eq $officeSelected }
       $server = $row.server
   explorer.exe \\$server
   
   
   }

Answer (score 0):

run a `foreach` loop to read each line from the csv till you find the `$office` you want.

```
Foreach ($line in $offices) {
         If ($line.office -eq $office) {
                 $server = $line.server  
         }
}
```

Comment: I couldnt get this to work AND show up in the combobox.